# support time of other Ubuntu LTS flavours?

Tags: support

I have read this [article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-mate-16-04-xenial-xerus-will-be-an-lts-release-supported-for-3-years-503116.shtml) from [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/why-can-t-we-get-5-years-support-for-16-04/5098/2) .It says that other Ubuntu flavors of LTS get only 3 years of support. Is this true?

This question is not a duplicate of the linked post as I want to know support time for only other Ubuntu flavors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run command

```
 ubuntu-support-status
```

source https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

I am using Ubuntu mate too, and in my system there are 75% packages are supported until 5 years.
this is screenshot of my Ubuntu mate 16.04 LTS
[image]

now running the command you can see that packages related to desktop environment are supported for 3 years and those system related are supported for 5 years.

now in this screenshot you can see that these packages are supported for 3 years and they are mostly related to mate desktop environment like caja,mate panel,mate-desktop-environment-core..etc
[image]

As Ubuntu flavors are based on some other desktop environment like lubuntu is  based on LXDE,these desktop environments are not in control of canonical which had made Ubuntu.but unity which is default desktop environment of the Ubuntu is made by canonical and thus they are in full control of the unity desktop environment,thus they provide 5 years of support to maximum packages.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting.

Comment: @muru thanks for suggestion.i did not coyed the text cause no one needs to copy this text as it just show the information.anyway , should i edit my answer?

Comment: Images of text have multiple significant drawbacks over actual text content: 1) you can't copy and paste it easily, 2) it's not searchable or indexable by search engines, 3) it's inaccessible to the visually impaired, 4) it's inaccessible without a graphical user interface (e. g. text-mode browsers). Aside from special situations where text colour or formatting need to be preserved or when it's difficult or impossible to copy and paste the source text there is no reason at all to use images of text instead of text. Even in those cases you can often provide both.

Comment: @DavidFoerster i will post text in sometime but should i keep images?

Comment: If you want to. I think nobody would object. Imho there's no benefit to it though.

Answer (score 3):

You may still get updates for a lot of other packages installed in your Ubuntu, because they are part of official repositories.

Just  run:

```
$ ubuntu-support-status
```

to get a list of all packages and their support status:

```
You have 12 packages (0.6%) supported until May 2022 (5y)
You have 1393 packages (71.5%) supported until April 2021 (5y)
You have 327 packages (16.8%) supported until April 2019 (3y)
```

I'm running "xenial", however as you see I've got some packages with 3 years support too.