Does installing Ubuntu Desktop on Xubuntu LTS adopt the longer Ubuntu support period
I have just noticed that my Xubuntu 20.04 device is already EOL. I did not know that it has a shorter support period (3 years) than regular Ubuntu (5 years). But alas here we are.
I have installed the ubuntu-desktop package on my device and switched to Ubuntu desktop. Does this mean that the device now inherits the longer support period of regular Ubuntu LTS?
If not is there some way I can get the longer Ubuntu LTS support period without having to reinstall my device from scratch?
Best regards

All the program packages that belong to (are part of) 'Ubuntu Desktop' are supported for the longer period. But the program packages that are specific for Xubuntu (the desktop as well as tools) are supported for the shorter period. So if you use only the Ubuntu desktop and only the programs that belong to Ubuntu, you will have the longer support.

Packages from main get five years of support; packages from the community repository (universe) meaning from flavor teams of upstream Debian come only with three years of guaranteed support; which ended at 2023-April.  You can use ubuntu-security-status (or ubuntu-support-status for older release) to view what packages are still getting security fixes and guaranteed support and which are not (ESM/Pro can also extend security too), but its more there is no guarantee of support for universe, as any MOTU or dev with upload rights can still fix packages until 2025-April anyway.

FYI:  To me I consider a Xubuntu 20.04 LTS system as a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system where the Xfce desktop is being used.. and I actually have a 20.04 system here still (Xubuntu + Lubuntu installed), but both Xubuntu, Lubuntu and other flavors have ended support for it (so please don't ask for it).. Your base Ubuntu system still gets upgrades, you've just lost guarantee for the flavor packages for security fixes etc.

@guiverc I don't see what https://askubuntu.com/questions/920392/support-time-of-other-ubuntu-lts-flavours has to do at all with my question. I already understand the support times of flavors. My question is specifically if or how I can adopt the longer support time by switching to ubuntu-desktop. I have already searched thoroughly and not found a direct answer.

@guiverc do you know if I uninstall the Universe packages so that I am for sure only using packages still getting support, if that would break my system?

Use packages from the main repository; as those are what have the five years of guaranteed support; and avoid packages from universe... The running of ubuntu-security-status I mentioned can provide details if you explore it.  You can happily remove all packages from universe if you wish; as the Ubuntu Desktop install includes NONE of them anyway.. however that tends to be rather limiting; as many users need more than what is provided on install media (packages on install media are those from main only!) but want additional packages....

I (like @sudodus who also answered) am involved with at least one flavor of Ubuntu.. and thus don't see packages from universe as a problem; they have just no longer covered by any guarantee of support since 3 years has elapsed...  If that (security issue) matters to you, fair enough....  but a MOTU or someone with uploads rights can still fix it until the five year mark; the gurantee of that occurring is really what has gone.

Packages from main get five years of support/security-fixes; packages from the community repository (universe) meaning from flavor teams or upstream Debian come only with three years of guaranteed support/security-fixes; which ended at 2023-April.
You can use ubuntu-security-status (or ubuntu-support-status for older releases) to view what packages are still getting security fixes and guaranteed support and which are not (ESM/Ubuntu Pro can also extend security for LTS releases by an additional five years too), but there is no guarantee of support for universe packages, as any MOTU or dev with upload rights can still fix packages until 2025-April anyway (i.e. 5 years is technically still there; which is why I use the guarantee wording)
FYI: As far as I'm concerned I consider a Xubuntu 20.04 LTS system as a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system where the Xfce desktop is being used.. and I actually have a 20.04 system here still (Xubuntu + Lubuntu installed), but both Xubuntu, Lubuntu and other flavors have ended support for it (so please don't ask for it). Your base Ubuntu system still gets upgrades, you've just lost guarantee for the flavor packages for security fixes, etc.
You can happily remove all packages from universe if you wish; as the Ubuntu Desktop install includes NONE of them anyway, however that tends to be rather limiting as many users need more than what is provided on the installation media (packages on Ubuntu Desktop install media are those from main only!) but want additional community packages.
You can install one Ubuntu system, and via package changes, convert it to another Ubuntu system or flavor desktop in any combination, though some settings may be different even after package changes to a install of final product.
i.e.
Yes, you can convert your Xubuntu 20.04 LTS system into an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop system (with five years of support), but personally I think that's a lot of effort that may not gain you much; as to really improve security can you live without universe packages? Adding Ubuntu Pro support may be a more security conscious option anyway.

I (like sudodus who also commented) am involved with at least one flavor of Ubuntu.. and thus don't see packages from universe as a problem; they have just no longer covered by any guarantee of support since 3 years has elapsed... If that (security issue) matters to you, fair enough.... but a MOTU or someone with uploads rights can still fix it until the five year mark; the guarantee of that occurring is really what has gone.   There are other difference between main & universe here... security benefits to main packages too that I've not covered here for brevity

Got it, thanks a lot

@fastraul just FYI, but a key difference between flavor ISOs and the main Ubuntu Desktop is just what packages are put on the ISO itself, as both Xubuntu & Ubuntu Desktop are built by same builders on launchpad (ie. contrast https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/xubuntu.focal/desktop with https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu.focal/desktop for example.. ie. seed files dictate what gets included)... Packages in main have longer guarantee of fixes, the Ubuntu Security Team perform checks on packages in main etc...

@karel, FYI: my intention of additional security with ESM/Ubuntu Pro was more the security benefits of having security patches for universe packages during the standard support life... that are offered; not the additional five years [of patches/security/support] that can be gained by ESM, or further two years if adding legacy too.  I touched on security a few times, but didn't see question as relating to beyond the standard support (5) years; maybe it was.

If my edit could be improved then please improve it.
