How long can I use previous LTS
The official flavours of Ubuntu LTS are suppose to only have 3 years support while the official one is suppose to last till 2027. Is it possible to use it beyond april 2025 or do I have to upgrade? Do official flavours support the same way as Canonical does ? I am using Xubuntu

See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/920392/support-time-of-other-ubuntu-lts-flavours (the question I meant to tag sorry)...   You can use ubuntu-security-status to see support; there is a guarantee for support for five years from packages in main, but shorter for universe; and flavor packages all come from universe or the community supported packages (Canonical provides guarantee for packages in main)

FYI:  I still have systems here that are running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but I'm using the Xfce desktop (Xubuntu) and LXQt desktop (Lubuntu)... in fact used a flavor ISO to install the system, but I now consider it a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system where I'm using Xfce/LXQt  (and I'm a flavor team member myself!).  Don't ask for support from flavors after the three years, but you're still supported here & by Ubuntu for five years.

Packages in universe can still be fixed for the full five years supported by Ubuntu; its just that there is a lack of volunteers to do the work, but a MOTU (master of the universe) or developer with upload privileges could still upload packages past the three years.. That in fact was done by Kubuntu/Lubuntu if I recall correctly a little past the three year mark for xenial [16.04] (or bionic [18.04]) but that is an exception.. Flavor teams usually ignore packages with problems after three years & there are so few MOTU's or others willing ..  Why I use the word guarantee
